# Proving the given inequality.

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

$z$ is any complex number , we need to prove that :

$|z^{4} + 5z^{2} +4|\geq ||z^{4}|-5|z^{2}|+4|$.

What I did :

I made use of the reverse triangle inequality : $|x-y|\geq ||x|-|y||$.

$|z^{4} + 5z^{2} +4| = |z^{4} + 5z^{2} -(-4)| \geq ||z^{4} + 5z^{2}| -4||$.

Now , $|z^{4} + 5z^{2}|=|z^{4} -(- 5z^{2})| \geq ||z^{4}| - |5z^{2}||$ , Combining this with the previous step , I got :

$||z^{4} + 5z^{2}| -4|| \geq ||z^{4}| - |5z^{2}|-4| = ||z^{4}| - 5|z^{2}|-4|$.

I am getting a negative sign before $4$ , could anyone tell what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: your last step doesn't do anything

Comment: Just because you got a different inequality doesn't mean you did a wrong step, it just means you have not found a tight enough bound. However in this case, you have used $|a|>|b| \implies ||a|-|c||>||b|-|c||$ which is not always valid.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

$$|z^2+1|\cdot|z^2+4|\ge||z^2|-1|\cdot ||z^2|-4|$$

Comment: I got it .. Thanks..
Just to clear my doubt , the proof above.. is it incorrect ? @Macavity

Comment: I have commented above on your approach.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$|z^{4} + 5z^{2} +4| = |z^{4} + 4 - (-5z^{2})|$$

Comment: But $|z^4+4|\le||z^4|+4|$ so you seem to land in a similar predicament as the OP.